# Get JSON child data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to get `phone` from my JSON data and playing around with D3.

```
[
{
    "id": "00000", 
    "type": "company", 
    "name": "Ideal-Phones", 
    "icon": "\uf1ad",
    "level" :"0",
    "display" : "block",
    "context": [
        {"context-id": "10000", "name": "phone"}
    ]
},
{
    "id": "00100",
    "type": "software",
    "name": "Jira",
    "icon": "\uf7b1",
    "parent" : "00000",
    "level" :"1",
    "display": "none",
    "context": [
        {"contxt-id": "10001", "name": "Jira"}
    ]
}
```

]

I am able to get the `level` with:

```
function click(d) {
console.log(d.level)}
```

.. and thought console.log(d.context.name) would do the trick.

Comment: `context` is an array, you need `d.context[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nick's comment, the type of `context` is an array. So you should access it by `index` like below

```js
var data = [
      {
          "id": "00000", 
          "type": "company", 
          "name": "Ideal-Phones", 
          "icon": "\uf1ad",
          "level" :"0",
          "display" : "block",
          "context": [
              {"context-id": "10000", "name": "phone"}
          ]
      }
   ];
var firstItem = data[0].context;
console.log("Is array: " + Array.isArray(firstItem));

var firstContext_of_firstItem = firstItem[0];
console.log("Value: " + firstContext_of_firstItem.name);
```

**More requirement: Loop and compare the `name` of property**

```js
var data = [
      {
          "id": "00000", 
          "type": "company", 
          "name": "Ideal-Phones", 
          "icon": "\uf1ad",
          "level" :"0",
          "display" : "block",
          "context": [
              {"context-id": "10000", "name": "phone"},
              {"context-id": "10001", "name": "Ideal-Phones"},
          ]
      }
   ];
   
for(let item of data){
  var name_of_item = item.name;
  for(let childContext of item.context){
    var name_of_child_context = childContext.name;
    if(name_of_item === name_of_child_context){
      // do something here
      console.log(childContext);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mai, so in case I want to compare those values I would need to iterate through each array right? Something like "ForEach if d.context[i].name === o.context[i].name { do.. }

Comment: Updated my answer with note **More requirement: Loop and compare the name of property**, pls take a look at @ICoded

Comment: I see. Thanks @Mai, I will adapt your code so I can compare different JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

This code will write to console the desired output "phone"

```
var txt = '[{\"id\":\"00000\",\"type\":\"company\",\"name\":\"Ideal-Phones\",\"icon\":\"\uf1ad\",\"level\":\"0\",\"display\":\"block\",\"context\":[{\"context-id\":\"10000\",\"name\":\"phone\"}]},{\"id\":\"00100\",\"type\":\"software\",\"name\":\"Jira\",\"icon\":\"\uf7b1\",\"parent\":\"00000\",\"level\":\"1\",\"display\":\"none\",\"context\":[{\"contxt-id\":\"10001\",\"name\":\"Jira\"}]}]'
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
alert(obj[0].context[0].name);
```